# How to add a Rest validation in array property of an object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I need to validate the request msisdn array type, I'm using rest validation of spring boot and how can I add the value in error message too.

I tried custom validation but I cannot find any array validation.

Desired error response

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Invalid msisdn: 0917854*****",
        "Invalid msisdn: 0936895*****"
    ],
    "success": false,
}
```

Request Body

```
{
  "msisdn": ["0917854*****", "0936895*****"],
  "message": "test message",
  "title": "test title"
}
```

java object

```java
public class PushNotif {

  //validate this List
    private List<String> msisdn;

    @NotNull(message = "Message is required")
    private String message;

    private String title;

    public PushNotif(List<String> msisdn, String message, String title) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
        this.message = message;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

java controller

```java
@RestController
public class PushController extends BaseController{

    @PostMapping(path = "/push")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> indexAction(@valid @RequestBody PushNotif pushNotif){

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(null,HttpStatus.ok);
    }
}
```

Error Response Handler

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{

    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> errors = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();

        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        });

        errors.put("details", details);
        errors.put("success", false);
        errors.put("traceid", "aksjdhkasjdhs-akjsdjksa-asjkdh");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I added Parameter constraints to my java object

```
 @NotNull(message = "msisdn is required")
    private List<@NotNull(message = "msisdn is required")
                 @Pattern(regexp = "^09[0-9]{9}",
                         message = "Invalid msisdn ${validatedValue}") String> msisdn;
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to validate values in a list, in this case values not null, you can add the `@NotNull` annotation in object reference type.

```
private List<@NotNull String> msisdn;
```

**References**
[Hibernate Validations for Nested Container Elements](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_nested_container_elements)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for your quick response.
how to add the value to the error message I need to display the msisdn number too in error
like this 
{
    "success": false,
    "details": [
        "Invalid msisdn 091785438641",
        "Invalid msisdn 093689534561"
    ]
}

Comment: If that is the case, then your should create a custom validator so that you validate the list and create a custom api error to display what you want to show.